# Reductive subgroup and its derived subgroup with an irreducible represenation

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups

Could you please answer the following question: Let $V$ be a faithful irreducible representation of a connected reductive group $H$ defined over $\mathbb{R}$ Is it true that the derived group of $H$, which is semisimple, also acts irreducibly on $V$?. For example $H = U(p/2,q/2) \subseteq SO(p,q)$, with $p,q$ both even, and $V$ is the natural representation of $SO(p,q)$.

Answer (score 1):

You should give a bit more motivation as to why you are asking this; it feels like an exercise in a book.

Anyway, this is not true: for a trivial example, take $G=SO(2)$ acting irreducibly on ${\mathbb R}^2$; the derived subgroup is trivial and does not act irreducibly.

If you want a truly semi-simple example, take $G=SO(n)\times SO(2)$ acting irreducibly on the exterior tensor power of the standard representations of $SO(n)$ and $SO(2)$: namely $V={\mathbb R}^n\otimes {\mathbb R}^2$, with $n\geq 3$. The derived group is $SO(n)$ and does not irreducibly on $V$.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I was wondering whether a proper closed connected reductive subgroup of $SO(p,q)$ of maximal rank can act on $V$ irreducibly but its derived group does not. I assume $p \neq q$ and $p,q$ sufficiently large. It seems to me, that there is only subgroup when $p,q$ are even, upto conjugacy, that is of full rank and satisfy the property: U(p/2,q/2). If instead of over $\mathbb{R}$ we consider over $\mathbb{C}$ it seems true: (I reason as follows) for if the center of $H$ is positive dimensional, then its eigenspaces are $H$-invariant. Thus $H$ is not reducible.

Comment: All the discussion is in terms of Zariski topology.

Comment: In my first comment I mean: If the center of $H$ has dimension greater than 0, then the eigenspaces of the center are $H$-invariant. It follows that $H$ is not irreducible. ( I wrote H is $not$ reducible, which is wrong).

Comment: @user49908: Yes, it is true that the only connected non-semisimple reductive $\mathbb{R}$-subgroup $H$ of full rank of the group $G=SO(p,q)$, that  satisfies the $\mathbb{R}$-irreducibility property, is, up to conjugacy, $U(p/2,q/2)$. This follows from Dynkin's classification of maximal reductive $\mathbb{C}$-Lie-subalgebras of simple $\mathbb{C}$-Lie-algebras. Dynkin was our contemporary, he passed away on November 14, 2014.

Comment: @user49908: If you ask a new question titled, say, "Irreducible reductive Lie subalgebras of $so(p,q)$", I will answer it.

Comment: I have asked a variant: Reducible reductive Lie subalgebras of so(p,q). Thank you.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/187684/reducible-reductive-lie-subalgebras-of-sop-q